# Ruby float to date time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got response from `Sidekiq::Worker` where `created_at` is a float

active_workers.map { |w| w.dig('created_at') }.first
=> 1653562493.6044002

How to change that value to date time? I've tried to do simple `.to_date` but it return me an error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `to_date' for 1653562493.6044002:Float

Comment: Try `Time.at(1653562493.6044002)`

Comment: @Stefan that's true! Please add an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding the answer mentioned in the comment by Stefan

```
Time.at(1653562493.6044002)
```

Also, if Timezone is a crucial factor we can use the below code as well

```
Time.zone.at(1653562493.6044002)
```